# Multiselect for Kendo UI Grid without Checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to work with multiselectable rows in a Kendo Grid without the extra column checkboxes?

I'm working with Angular but can't find any possibility to get an multiselectable Grid without the checkboxes.

Comment: Doesn't the selectable option work for you?  If you set it to "multiple, row" then you can use CTRL/SHIFT clicking to select and unselect rows. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-selectable, http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/selection.

Comment: This work for desktop yes. But I like to make a responsive design.
With my smartphone it won't work.

Comment: Drag-selecting works on my phone(draw a box with your finger and lift will select all rows in the box).  Haven't figured out the sequence for selecting non-contiguous blocks yet, though.